# Where is the category of a post stored?

Tags: categories

I'm returning to WP after some time away, and find I've forgotten what little I knew.

I have some pages on a site that display a post of given category, which was done with a line like: `query_posts($query_string . '&cat=2');`

followed by:
`if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` etc. etc. ending with (else) 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria'

I have defined a category 'Services', and assigned a test post to this category. I can see in `wp_terms` that the category has the term_id of 2 and name of 'Services', but the post isn't getting picked up.

Where is the post 'told' what its category is? Should I be expecting to see a field for `category_id` (or `cat_id`) somewhere? It's certainly not in the `wp_posts` record.

Or, in other words, where is the query string `&cat=2` picked up?

It certainly used to work, but that was a while ago and maybe some updates to WP or PHP now require a change?

Answer (score 3):

`wp_terms`, `wp_term_taxonomy`, `wp_term_relationships` and `wp_term_meta` these 4 tables powers the WordPress taxonomy world. You'll find the relation between post and term within these 3 tables `wp_terms`, `wp_term_taxonomy`, `wp_term_relationships`. You have to start journey from `wp_term_relationships`. If you wanna know more about DB schema https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-and-working-with-data-in-wordpress--cms-20567

And `query_posts()` is harmful and bad practice, it overrides the WordPress main query. Better you should use a custom query.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
        'cat' => 2, // category id goes here
    ) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        // do the whatever you wanna do inside the loop
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: I found that changing my opening line to 'query_posts('cat=2')' (doing away with the $query_string variable) worked as I wanted. Quite why there's been a change I do not know. I should have explained that this is only a 'partial' WP site, most of the pages are regular HTML/PHP, just a few are in WP so that the site owner can make edits.